# EKS Service deployment not updating?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

When I try to apply a new Service deployment yaml in AWS EKS, it does not delete the old load balancer from the previous build/deploy

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # The name must be equal to KubernetesConnectionConfiguration.serviceName
  name: ignite-service
  # The name must be equal to KubernetesConnectionConfiguration.namespace
  namespace: ignite
  annotations:
   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
  labels:
    app: ignite
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: rest
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: thinclients
      port: 10800
      targetPort: 10800
  # Optional - remove 'sessionAffinity' property if the cluster
  # and applications are deployed within Kubernetes
  #  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  selector:
    # Must be equal to the label set for pods.
    app: ignite
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I had a situation where I deployed a ELB, but this time a NLB, but it would not destroy the previous ELB.

Is there a way to when applying the k8s manifest, the old load balancer on AWS gets deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are using to create the resources **helm**, **resources** or **kubectl** however consider the **kubectl** as of now

you can use the

```
 kubectl replace --force -f <service-filename>.yaml
```